# Highchart crashing with multiple Y axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My highchart crashes chrome, when i add the 2nd serie.
Cannot see Chrome console to debug.. :(
Does anyone have an idea?

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                margin: [40,10,60,80],
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature Today'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',    
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    day: '%H:%M'
                },
                tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    align: 'right',

                    style: {
                        fontSize: '10px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                },
            }, 
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature'
                },
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                /* gridLineWidth: 0, */
                /* alternateGridColor: null */
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return ''+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.x) +': '+ this.y;
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                spline: {
                    lineWidth: 4,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 3
                        }
                    },
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true,
                                symbol: 'circle',
                                radius: 3,
                                lineWidth: 1
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }
            },
            series: [{
                    name: 'Temperature',
                    data: temp,
                    type: 'line',
                    showInLegend: false,
                    pointInterval: 60 * 1000,
                    pointStart: Date.UTC(2006, 0, 1),
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                    dashStyle: 'solid',
                    yAxis: 0,
                    xAxis: 0,
                    } , {
                    name: 'Humdity',
                    data: hum,
                    yAxis: 1,
                    xAxis: 0,
                    showInLegend: false,
                    type: 'line',
             }],
            navigation: {
                menuItemStyle: {
                    fontSize: '6px'
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: It even crashes on JSfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You only have one `yAxis`, so it breaks because you set the second serie to display into the second one( yes, that's what `yAxis: 1` means ).

Remove it or create the second `yAxis`.

**Update**:

- Use `yAxis: 0` the reffer the first and `1` to the second.
- Missing `,` after `}` on line 36 of jsfiddle.
- Store data before.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/vDGGj/3/)

Comment: I cannot see anything in here that actives another Y axis?http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

Comment: @HyperDevil Because there isn't other yAxis in this demo. It's composed by one `yAxis` (left side), a `xAxys`(middle) and `legends`(right side).

Comment: @HyperDevil Take a look the following demo. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes

Comment: @HyperDevil Again, you should show the data you're using to create your series (`hum` and `temp`). So that I can test, see what's the problem and create a working demo.

Comment: @HyperDevil Take a look my update and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks, now it does not crash, but i dont see the lines itself. http://jsfiddle.net/vDGGj/2/

Comment: @HyperDevil You should add your data before create the chart ;). http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/vDGGj/3/

Comment: on my server it is already included before highchart starts. Unfortunanly it's still kaput. here is the URL: 63.gradernord.no/js.php